# Peephole Viewer Project, Model B or B+? Accessories? Feasibility?

Tags: camera, display

I'm trying to put together a project that will allow me to put a Raspberry Pi on my door with the PiCam Module and display the video stream *(NOT SAVE IT)* from the peephole on a TFT touch screen connected to it.

Note: This is for my use on the viewer side of the peephole, not for spying on people by being on the "viewee" side of the peephole.

Is this a possible project? I'm super new to the Pi Community

If so, should I purchase a Model B or Model B+ model? Currently I hear maybe the B would be better but I'd rather buy the best one since I currently don't own one.

This is my proposed shopping cart:

- Miniature WiFi Module - Official Raspberry Pi Edition PID: 2638
- 5V 2A  Switching Power Supply w/ 20AWG 6' MicroUSB Cable PID: 1995
- 8GB SD Card with Raspbian Jessie Operating System PID: 2767
- Adafruit Raspberry Pi B+ / Pi 2 Case - Smoke Base w/ Clear Top PID: 2258
- Raspberry Pi 2 - Model B - ARMv7 with 1G RAM PID: 2358
- Raspberry Pi Camera Board PID: 1367
- RCA (Composite Video, Audio) Cable 6 feet PID: 863
- PiTFT - Assembled 480x320 3.5" TFT+Touchscreen for Raspberry Pi PID: 2097

Any tips?

Comment: I'm fairly sure shopping recommendations are off topic.

Comment: @joan it's not recommendations it's about project feasibility.

Comment: Are you referring to the model 2 B when you say model B or the original model B.

Comment: @PatrickCook model 2 B. 1GB ram

Comment: Actually you would have the capability to send the images to another RPi or a PC on your Home network - it could even be extended (suitable door hardware permitting) to allow you review (switch a connected TV/Monitor to show the picture when it gets one) and to open the door remotely, say from your sofa perhaps! *Facial recognition* - it sees your mug in the view-finder and opens the door to you *might* be a bit optimistic though, as you wouldn't want it to let someone in who just holds a photo of you in front of it... 8-)

Comment: wouldnt it be better to buy something like rmrc pico camera with transmission module and receiver + some cheap AV monitor (like the one from Quantum DIY 2) ? You got everything working in 10 seconds... without any raspberry... search terms in google: "rmrc Pico FPV Combo V2", "quantum diy 2"... to be honest I am using it that way and it's kinda cool... image quality is better than 480x320. 900mhz is perfect for wall penetration... much better than 2.4Ghz

Answer (score 2):

The Model 2 B would probably be your best option, since it's higher processing speed and more RAM would decrease the latency on the video stream and possible allow for higher framerates/quality.